# New java version installation run error

Tags: 12.04, java

I just installed a new version of Java jre1.7.0_07 it is all installed and I have already set it as my default Java using

```
sudo update-alternatives --config java
```

However when I go to fire up a program with Java I get an error

```
java: relocation error: java: symbol JLI_MemAlloc, version SUNWprivate_1.1 not defined in file libjli.so with link time reference
```

there is one other version of Java on the system that was the default. I am completely at a loss for what to do I have researched this topic a bit but could find no resolution.

Any help would be greatly appreciated or at least a link to an answer.

Answer (score 1):

I think that happens because you have Java executable from one OpenJDK and the rest of binaries from Oracle. Purge one of them manually.